# Sort a dataframe by a `label` column, shuffle per each `label`, preserve order per `group`

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, shuffle

Given the following dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': ['all', 'moon', 'less', 'cat', 'pen' , 'dark', 'pile'],
                        'label': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                        'group': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']})
```

output:

```
    value      label  group
0   'all'      0      'A'
1   'moon'     1      'B'
2   'less'     1      'B'
3   'cat'      0      'B'
4   'pen'      1      'A'
5   'dark'     0      'B'
6   'pile'     0      'A'
```

I like to generate a new `dataframe` with the following conditions:

> 1. Rows are sorted by label
> 2. Per each label, rows are shuffled
> 3. But maintaining order based on the value

So for example, here is a possible outcome:

```
    value      label  group
0   'all'      0      'A'
3   'cat'      0      'B'
5   'dark'     0      'B'
6   'pile'     0      'A'
2   'less'     1      'B'
4   'pen'      1      'A'
1   'moon'     1      'B'
```

So regarding condition 3, `'pile'` comes after `'all'` both with the same label and from the same group. Any other shuffle and sort, shouldn't allow `'pile'` to come before `'all'`.

Or another one with a different shuffle:

```
    value      label  group
3   'cat'      0      'B'
0   'all'      0      'A'
6   'pile'     0      'A'
5   'dark'     0      'B'
4   'pen'      1      'A'
2   'less'     1      'B'
1   'moon'     1      'B'
```

Any thoughts on a clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite complex to achieve.

First shuffle completely the dataframe using `sample(frac=1)`:

```
# np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility
df2 = df.sample(frac=1).sort_values(by='label', ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
    value  label group
0  'pile'      0   'A'
1   'cat'      0   'B'
2   'all'      0   'A'
3  'dark'      0   'B'
4  'less'      1   'B'
5  'moon'      1   'B'
6   'pen'      1   'A'
```

Then sort the values by label and determine the sorting order per group:

```
idx = (df2.reset_index()                  # save index as column
       .sort_values(by='value')           # sort values
       .groupby(['label', 'group'])['index']  # reorder the index per value
       .transform(sorted).sort_values()       # using sorted
       .index
      )
# Int64Index([2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Finally use this to reindex your `df2`:

```
df2.loc[idx]
```

output:

```
    value  label group
2   'all'      0   'A'
1   'cat'      0   'B'
0  'pile'      0   'A'
3  'dark'      0   'B'
4  'less'      1   'B'
5  'moon'      1   'B'
6   'pen'      1   'A'
```

Comment: If you get a chance, can you explain the second operation a bit? Also, do we need `reset_index` right after `df2` in the second operation since `ignore_index=True` in the first operation?

Comment: yes we need the reset index to keep track of the original index. I'll try to comment a bit, but the best is probably to comment all lines in the second code and uncomment one by one to see what happens